# what HTML options can be used for the form_for method in FormHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[FormHelper's form_for method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) has the signature:

> form_for(record, options = {}, &block)

. The second parameter is an options hash. The documentation states that this is

> :html - Optional HTML attributes for the form tag

I am having trouble finding the list of values that I could plug in to it.

I recently had to add a file field to my form.

The code used was something like `<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>`. Searching online lead me to the solution that I needed to use  `:html => { :multipart => true }`.

What other values (apart from  `:multipart => true`) could I use? Is there a list of usable HTML attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default list of options are: `multipart`, `method`, `authenticity_token`, list of parameters to append to the URL the form gets posted to, `remote`, and `enforce_utf8`.

Please see [documentation of `form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) for further reference, and [`html_options_for_form_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L806) for how these options are processed.

Comment: thanks! I am very new at Rails and all this information is very much appreciated. But why is it that the code for form_for located in form_tag's source code?

Comment: @user571099, it's not that `form_for`'s code is in `form_tag`, they are different helpers.  `form_for` simplifies attaching model's instance, route to controller action whereas `form_tag` creates form tag without relying on an AR object.  If you look at the source of the two you'll find that both these helpers call `html_options_for_form` method.  Please see [`form_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L413) and [`form_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L67).

Answer (score 0):

`:html` - Optional HTML attributes for the form tag. There are other options like:

```
:html => { :class => "edit_post", :id => "edit_post_45" }<br/>
:html => { :method => :delete }<br/>
:html => { :class => "new_post", :id => "new_post" }<br/>
:html => { :class => "edit_post", :id => "edit_post_45" }**
```